# How to get data from First Fragment to Last Fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have multiple fragments in ViewPager. How can i get fragment first EditText Data to last Fragment?

I have set value in my first fragment like below -

```
 txtConsAcNo.setText(account_no);
 txtMeterSrMo.setText(mtr_serial_no);
```

Now i am getting this txtConsAcNo, txtMeterSrMo value on my last fragment like below-

```
 ConDetFirstFragment f1 = new ConDetFirstFragment();
 txtConsAcNo = f1.txtConsAcNo.getText().toString();
 txtMeterSrMo = f1.txtMeterSrMo.getText().toString();
```

Now what i want that i am getting Null value and my app get unfortunately stopped. i want to get this data to my last fragment without bundle. how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Easy to Achieve this without Creating Interface, Bundle or intent -

I have declared all the variables in all the fragment "Public Static" like Below -

```
public static EditText txtConsAcNo, txtMeterSrMo;
```

After on any fragment i have declared variable to get data like below-

```
public static String txtConsAcNo,txtMeterSrMo;
```

Now i have created function to get value from first fragment in above variable below-

```
public static void getalldata(){
        ConDetFirstFragment f1 = new ConDetFirstFragment();
        txtConsAcNo = f1.txtConsAcNo.getText().toString();
        txtMeterSrMo = f1.txtMeterSrMo.getText().toString();
}
```

Happy Coding...

Comment: Are you sure this is the best way? Keeping references like this is not good because your classes will have tight coupling

Comment: Accept my answer to help others.

Comment: Let the OP try the best solution before accepting the answer; that is how SO works!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. The first fragment may have been destroyed by the Android system to conserve memory.
2. Your fragments should not talk to each other directly

To achieve what you need, you need to jump through a few hoops.

1. Assuming that the source texts are EditText objects (ie. editable by the user), then add a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to each of the EditText objects.
2. Create an Interface:

   ```
   public interface TextPurveyor {
        void setText1(String t);
        String getText1();
        void setText2(String t);
        String getText1();
   }
   ```
3. Implement this interface in the host Activity; and save the text values locally in the activity. Don't forget to save/restore them with the rest of the Activity state.
4. Make the TextWatcher objects call the appropriate setText(..) methods on the host activity:

   ```
   ((TextPurveyor)getActivity()).setText1(...);
   ```
5. Make each fragment check that the host activity implements this method.
6. When the second fragment wants a string, ask the activity for it:

   ```
   ((TextPurveyor)getActivity()).getText1();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid coupling your project code tightly, try to use the design patterns that have been proven to work best like the `Publisher/Subscriber` as I will show you below:

There is a popular library I have always used in my projects called `EventBus` - just add the following to your `build.gradle` (module-level) file under dependencies :

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Secondly, create a simple `Plain Old Java Object (POJO)` to represent your Event:

```
public class FragmentAToLastEvent{
   private String txtConsAcNo;
   private String txtMeterSrMo;

   FragmentAToLastEvent(String acNo, String srMO){
      this.txtConsAcNo = acNO;
      this.txtMeterSrMo = srMO;
   }

   //getters and setters if needed
   public String gettxtConsAcNo(){
       return txtConsAcNo;
   }

   public String gettxtMeterSrMo(){
       return txtMeterSrMo;
   }
}
```

Next step is to actually use your Event class here:

So, in your fragment that you want to send text from `EditText`, simply do this:

```
String txtConsAcNo = f1.txtConsAcNo.getText().toString();
String txtMeterSrMo = f1.txtMeterSrMo.getText().toString();
EventBus.getDefault().post(new FragmentAToLastEvent(txtConsAcNo, txtMeterSrMo));
```

In your last fragment, simply do this to complete:

Inside `onCreate` or `onAttach` of your Fragment:

```
//register your event - making this class a subscriber
EventBus.getDefault().register(this)

//next, override a single method to receive the values you passed from above code (Fragment 1?)

public void onEvent(FragmentAToLastEvent event){

   String txtConsAcNo = event.gettxtConsAcNo();
   String txtMeterSrMo = event.gettxtMeterSrMo();

   //now you can use your text here without problems!
}
```

Finally, remember to unregister inside onDestroy:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
   super.onDestroy();

   EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

This is what I have always done and it is cleaner, without using interfaces that your fragments MUST implement and do all that!

I hope you find it helpful to you and good luck!